# Hide/Show Multiple Column in V-Data-Table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frameworks, vuetify.js

May I ask for your help, I'm currently working making the columns show/hide using vuetifyjs, I stumbled on these reference:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jeWRvN

```
computedHeaders () {
  if(this.hideCalories){
    return this.headers.filter(header => header.text !== "Calories")
  }

  return this.headers;
}
```

},

My problem on it is that it can only hide 1 header/column.
Can you help me to make it hide multiple headers.
I want to achieve these kind of output:

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: do you want to hide fat and carbs headers also and their columns ?

Comment: What are all the columns need to hide? you just want to remove the specific columns or remove all, on click on the Hide Calories?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim my apologies if it was not that clear, I've edited my question/post with an image. Hopefully that would make it more clearer. thank you guys

Comment: @Sam my apologies if it was not that clear, I've edited my question/post with an image. Hopefully that would make it more clearer. thank you guys

Comment: the screenshot doesn't correspond to the codepen snippet

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim as you've mentioned, yes I also want to hide fat, carbs and protein header and instead of buttons to toggle it I'm planning on to use checkbox just like in the screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `headers` property can be computed

```js
  computed: {
    headers() {
      let headers = [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        }
      ]

      if (!this.hideCalories) {
        headers.push({ text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' })
      }
      if (!this.hideFat) {
        headers.push({ text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' })
      }
      // ...

      headers.push({ text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' })
      headers.push({ text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' })
      headers.push({ text: 'Actions', value: 'name', sortable: false })

      return headers
    }
  }
```

Then pass `headers` to table as before.